# Apache SNI, 2 domains, 2 certs, resolves to same document root

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, sni

I am currently following the following guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04

Setup so far has been problem free. I am using two class 1 certificates that I have registered at http://www.startssl.com/?app=21. Each is mapped to its own (correct) domain.

The problem is this: going to either domain under https resolves to the same document root, i.e. if I go to https://backend.domain2.com, I correctly come to the doc root indicated in its VirtualHost configuration. However, if I go to https://email.domain1.com, I get sent to the root of backend.domain2, URL remaining intact, with a warning that the SSL certificate is invalid. An inspection of the "invalid" certificate reveals that it is the one connected to backend.domain2.

What am I doing wrong here? the VirtualHost configs for both domains are below:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName mail.domain1.se
        ServerAdmin christopher.svanefalk@gmail.com
        ServerAlias www.mail.domain1.se

        DocumentRoot /usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/domain1.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/domain1.key
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #Alias /mail "/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail/"

        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail/$1

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName backend.domain2.com
    ServerAdmin christopher.svanefalk@gmail.com
    #ServerAlias www.domain2.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/backend.domain2.com/html

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    #Alias /mail "/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail/"

    #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/pegasusgbg.se/html/$1

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain2.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domain2.key
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

My ports.conf config is:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Did you add `NameVirtualHost *:443` to your configuration?

Comment: Yes, I will append my ports.conf above, just a moment.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue on 2.4.7 (Ubuntu LTS). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This..

```
ServerName mail.domain1.se
ServerAdmin christopher.svanefalk@gmail.com
ServerAlias www.mail.domain1.se
```

..and this..

```
ServerName backend.domain2.com
#ServerAlias www.domain2.com
```

..both don't match with the hostname you're saying you're visiting, `https://domain1.com`.  These hostnames will need to match exactly with what's being requested in the browser for the correct certificate to be served to the client.

Comment: domain1.com etc was supposed to be a generic item, the real domain name is actually backend.domain2.com etc. I will update my code so there is no confusion.

Comment: When you update, please use `example.com` and `example.org` instead of `domain1.com` etc. It's rude to use domains owned by someone else.

Comment: @chrsva Can you add the output of `apachectl -S` as well?

Comment: @JennyD - respectfully, domain1.com and domain2.com are not owned by anyone, or I would not have used them.

Comment: s/not owned/not currently owned/ - example.[com|net|org] are specifically set aside for this purpose. Of course, it would have been better still if you hadn't obfuscated your domain name at all; that way the people spending their free time trying to help you would have been able to verify how it looks from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, are you using a browser version that supports SNI? According to Wikipedia ,

```
 As of November 2012, the only major user bases whose browsers do not support 
 SNI appear to be users of Android 2.x (default browser)[2], Internet Explorer 
 on Windows XP[3][4] and versions of Java before 1.7 on any operating system.[5]
```

or a more detailed list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Client_side

Comment: I have tried it across 3 separate browsers - the latest Chrome, Firefox and Konqueror. All yield the same issue, and all support SNI. I am rather certain it is a server problem.